# Git Usage with PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell, automation

My team plans on automating numerous DBA processes and is looking into using a Git Repository for maintaining our PowerShell scripts. We manage numerous servers (lab, dev, and prod environment). Can I use Git to deploy the scripts to all of our servers when a change is made? Our DBA tasks involve remotely logging into a server and running the PowerShell script from that server. Right now our scripts are stored on Microsoft's SharePoint and our DBAs have to extract scripts from SharePoint each time they need to perform an automation task. This can be confusing because sometimes the files are already there from a previous task and the DBA is unsure if these scripts are the most recent.

1. Can I use Git to deploy scripts directly to servers whenever a change is made?
2. Is Git even used with PowerShell that often and how useful can Git actually be to my team?
3. Outside of version control and deployment, what other ways can a DBA make use of Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this question is primarily opinion-based, I have some possible answers:

1. Yes, you can, sort of. You need a bare repository in the server to receive the pull.
2. Git is so used with PowerShell that a package exists for this. Please, read https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Powershell
3. This is really based on your opinion/needs on what needs to/should be versioned. You could version SQL scripts, migration scripts, schemas, and the sort. You could even version the database files themselves, but I don't see the point on doing that.